# Function using to much memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

I have a function which is called by a button in a table view cell, after a 15-20 calls to the function (15 - 20 clicks on a button) I get a level 2 memory warning. Without this function I don't seem to get this error.

I've read up on the whole "memory responsibility" that comes with developing applications for iPhone but my inexperience is preventing me from implementing this on my function, so I'm hoping someone out there could take a look at it and see what might be sucking up all the memory.

The function **(edited: "(int)sender" -> "(id)sender")**:

```
- (void)addPoint:(id)sender {
if ([sender tag] == 0) {
    [playerOneScore replaceObjectAtIndex:holeNum withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[playerOneScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] intValue] + 1]];
} if ([sender tag] == 1) {
    [playerTwoScore replaceObjectAtIndex:holeNum withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[playerTwoScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] intValue] + 1]];
} if ([sender tag] == 2) {
    [playerThreeScore replaceObjectAtIndex:holeNum withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[playerThreeScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] intValue] + 1]];
} if ([sender tag] == 3) {
    [playerFourScore replaceObjectAtIndex:holeNum withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[playerFourScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] intValue] + 1]];
}
[tbl reloadData];
}
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers on how to release some memory from my function, the function is useless the way it's behaving right now.

Note: I've tried `[button release]` but this only seems to be creating errors and not really seem to help my memory situation.

Thank you in advance, Tobias Tovedal

**EDIT:**
cellForRowAtIndex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50]];

UIButton *plusBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
plusBtn.frame = CGRectMake(255, 5, 60, 70);
[plusBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[plusBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];
[plusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addPoint:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *minusBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
minusBtn.frame = CGRectMake(190, 5, 60, 70);
[minusBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[minusBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];
[minusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removePoint:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

plusBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
minusBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [cell.textLabel setText:[[playerOneScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] stringValue]];
} if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    [cell.textLabel setText:[[playerTwoScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] stringValue]];
} if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    [cell.textLabel setText:[[playerThreeScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] stringValue]];
} if (indexPath.row == 3) {
    [cell.textLabel setText:[[playerFourScore objectAtIndex:holeNum] stringValue]];
}

[cell.contentView addSubview:plusBtn];
[cell.contentView addSubview:minusBtn];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why does it say (int)sender, not (id)sender? and you could then do [sender tag]

Comment: Post the code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I'm almost sure that reloading the data is causing leak.

Comment: @XenElement You are correct, edited now. (Think I had something else send an int before for some reason)

Comment: @taskinoor I've added the rest of the code.

Comment: Have you tried running this through Instruments to see what type of object is taking up so much memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you are accessing your table cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you are adding the `minusBtn` and `plusBtn` subviews.

You should rearrange your code so these subviews are only added to the cell when it is created. As it is now new buttons are added also if it is being reused and thus already contains these views.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the plusBtn and minusBtn each time the cell is displayed without ever removing them.
Try moving the

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:plusBtn];
[cell.contentView addSubview:minusBtn];
```

code inside the block:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

**Edit:** Claus was faster

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and adding as subview `plusBtn` and `minusBtn` every time the method is called regarding the cell is reused or not. Adding as subview every time without removing the previous one is causing the leak. Try this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   UIButton *plusBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   plusBtn.frame = CGRectMake(255, 5, 60, 70);
   [plusBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [plusBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];
   [plusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addPoint:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   [cell.contentView addSubview:plusBtn];

   // do the same for minusBtn here
}
```